# How to reduce the line thickness of an imported image in inkscape

Tags: image, image-processing, inkscape

I've opened the following image in Inkscape. I want to reduce the thickness of the black lines/curves in it.

Since this is not a vector image, I am not sure how to reduce the thickness
of the lines in this image.

Could someone please help me with this?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Please post this kind of questions on [graphic design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).